# Exception when calling jQuery.fadeIn with a callback function from Dart

Tags: dart

Based on:

[How do I create an anonymous JavaScript function/callback with Dart's JS interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799289/how-do-i-create-an-anonymous-javascript-function-callback-with-darts-js-interop)

I have written this Dart function:

```dart
fadeIn(String selector) {

    Completer completer = new Completer();

    context.callMethod("\$", [selector]).callMethod("fadeIn", [FADE_SPEED, () {
        print("callback");
        completer.complete();
    }]);

    return completer.future;

}
```

Which should do (in JavaScript) `$(selector).fadeIn( FADE_SPEED, function() { console.log("bacllback");`.

However, when running this function in Dartium, I get the following exception:

> Exception: type '() => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'.

I don't understand the Exception. What have I done wrong?

The message "callback" does get printed out to the console though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an argument to the following callback

change

```dart
[FADE_SPEED, () {
```

to

```dart
[FADE_SPEED, (e) {
```

Often the underscore is used to indicate that the argument should be ignored

```dart
[FADE_SPEED, (_) {
```

The error message indicates that one argument was provided but the provided callback method accepts none.