# Use dart callback for wrapped js

Tags: javascript, dart, angular-dart

I wrapped exif-js library via `dart:js`.

```
  @JS()
    library exif;

    import 'package:js/js.dart';

    @JS()
    external PhotoDetails get EXIF;

    @JS()
    class PhotoDetails {
      factory PhotoDetails() {
        return EXIF;
      }

      @JS()
      external bool getData(img, callback);
}
```

And have a little Dart program:

```
PhotoDetails photoDetails = new PhotoDetails();
    var fileUploadInputElement = new FileUploadInputElement();
    fileUploadInputElement.onChange.listen((e) => photoDetails.getData(
        fileUploadInputElement.files[0], () {
      print(this);
    }));
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799289/how-do-i-create-an-anonymous-javascript-function-callback-with-darts-js-interop) it was already answered, but when I made so, I have this js error: `exif.js:351 Uncaught TypeError: callback.call is not a function`
I tried to cast manually to Function. But it has not helped. With lambda expression it was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `allowInterop` or `allowInteropCaptureThis`

```
PhotoDetails photoDetails = new PhotoDetails();
var fileUploadInputElement = new FileUploadInputElement();
fileUploadInputElement.onChange.listen((e) => photoDetails.getData(
    fileUploadInputElement.files[0], allowInteropCaptureThis((self, [_]) {
  print(self);
})));
```

Comment: I am not sure, that your answer is reason, but now it throws `Uncaught Unhandled exception:
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'

NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'call'
Receiver: Closure: () => dynamic
Tried calling: call(Instance of 'FileImpl')
Found: call()
#0      Object._noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:42)
#1      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)`

Comment: I updated my answer (added `[_, __]`). Can you please try if this has any effect (different error, ...)?

Comment: This not crashing, but for a pity print a "". So now I need to go deeper and find my mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `print(_);` instead of `print(this)`. `_` and `__` are just names for unused variables. You can use proper names for them instead. `[...]` is to make them optional because I didn't know how many parameters are tried to pass and just used two of them. I assume the first is `this` (not sure, it's a while I tried this myself)

Comment: Yes, this works. Very big thanks! Can you edit your answer?

Comment: Glad to hear you could make it work. I updated the answer.